# Prove that a continuous $f$ in $(0,1)$ can be extended into its one-point compactification if the limit at both end point exist and equal

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> > Let $X = (0,1)$. Consider the one-point compactification of $X$ (which is homeomorphism to $S^{1}$). Prove that a bounded continuous function $f:(0,1) \rightarrow R$ is extendable to this compactification if and only if the limits $\lim_{x\to 0+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 1-}f(x)$ exist and equal

Hi everybody. I have some problem related to compactification. The point is: this problem can be imagined intuitively but I can't prove it formally. So please give me a clear, formal proof with enough persuasive statement. Thanks.

Comment: Would you be convinced by a proof that a function between non-compact spaces extends iff the function is a proper function, i.e., if the inverse image of a compact set is compact? Also, do you know what is the topology used in the compactified spaces, to be able to show that the extension is continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_\infty=X\sqcup\left\{\infty\right\}$ be the one-poit compactification of $X$. By definition, a basic neighborhood of $\infty$ in $X_\infty$ is a set of the form $(0,\delta_1)\cup(1-\delta_2,1)\cup\left\{\infty\right\}$ for $0<\delta_1,\delta_2<1$.

If $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, bounded and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-}f(x)=:L$, define $f(\infty)=L$. Using the fact above, it should be easy for you to show that $f:X_\infty\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $\infty$, and it is obviously continuous at points of $X$, since $X$ is open in $X_\infty$
and it's topology is induced by $X_\infty$'s topology.

On the other hand, if $f$ can be continuously extended to $X_\infty$, use again the fact about basicc neighborhoods of $\infty$ and show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-}f(x)=f(\infty)$.

Comment: Very clear. Thanks so much Luiz...

Answer (score 1):

Let $X^{\ast} = X\cup\{p\}$ be the one-point compactification, and define $f(p)$ to be that limit value. Now, $f$ is continuous at $p$ because, for any open set $U = (f(p) - \epsilon,f(p)+\epsilon)$ containing $f(p)$, $f^{-1}(U)$ contains $p$, and $\exists 0 < x_0 < x_1 < 1$ such that
$$
f(x) \in U \quad\forall x < x_0, \text{ and } x > x_1
$$
Hence,
$$
f^{-1}(U) \text{ contains } (0,x_0)\cup (x_1,1)\cup\{p\}
$$
and the latter is a neighbourhood of $p$.

Comment: Thanks. You make the problem clear for me right now ...